# Design ideas for a webapp in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I'm working on a user based, social networking type of web application in Django.  It's my first one so I would like to make sure I'm using some good practices.

Currently the web app supports two kinds of users.  This is represented by two different Groups.  When I register a user I assign them to one of these two groups.  I also have two apps, one for each type of user.  The apps handle whatever things are distinct to a particular type of user.  I have another app that handles the actual authentication.  This app uses Django's built in User type and assigns them a UserProfile.  The two different types of users have their own profiles which extend/inherit from UserProfile.

This works reasonably well, and is fairly reusable since the authentication app can pull the user type from the url and figure out which type of user to create.  Since the groups are named conveniently, they can be added to the correct group too.

1. Is this the best way or are there more preferred, tried and true ways to handle this?  It seems like a pretty common enough scenario.  I don't want to continue incorrectly reinventing the wheel if I don't have to.
2. I was thinking of adding another app called, common, or something which would handle things that are common to all users.  For example, viewing a users profile page might be something anyone who is logged in might want to do, regardless of what type of user they are.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy part first, with 2) you're spot on. That would be the simplest and most effective way of doing that. It makes sense instead of replicating functionality across both applications to have one app that handles things that are common to both user types.

Back to 1)

With both profiles extending from UserProfile, you'd run into the issue of (if you were using get_profile() on a User object - see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) that you'd get back just a UserProfile object, not knowing which group the user actually belongs to based on the object received. This is because they both extend UserProfile but UserProfile would not be able to be (I believe) abstract, because you want every User to have a pointer to a UserProfile object which may actually be a UserGroup1 or a UserGroup2 object.

What I would suggest you do is make two seperate Models, that do not extend from the same Model (out of necessity): Group1 and Group2. You would store the information that is common to both profiles in the UserProfile of the User object. Then in the UserProfile you would have a ForeignKey to both a Group1 and a Group2 object:

```
group1 = models.ForeignKey(Group1, blank=True, null=True)
```

You would have to do the logic checking yourself, to ensure that only one is ever valid (you could just do this in an overridden save() method or something), but then to grab all of a user's data at once, and also know which group they are on you could do the following:

```
User.objects.filter(username='blahblah').select_related('profile', 'profile__group1', 'profile__group2')
```

Only one query to the database would give you all the information you'd need about a user, and you'd also know which group they are in (the one that isn't 'None').

I hope that helps.

P.S. I am assuming in this that groups don't just have unique data to each other, but also unique functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  That was a problem I had awhile ago.  I'm used to java where if I had an inheritance hierarchy I could automatically get the child class that I want.  I overcame this problem in python with adding a couple of methods to UserProfile which allow you to retrieve the appropriate child class so I'm not worried about that.  I'm glad that I was right in factoring out commonalities into a seperate app.  What about the situation of a user wanting to view the profile of another user?  There are different types of users, so how should this work?

Comment: You'd do this kind of view from your common app and then use the django include template command to render the group information based on the group of the user ({% include 'group1.html' %}), making sure to pass the variables from the common view of both the user's group1 and group2, so that at least one of them would be correct.